# Is there a way to remove UITabBar/or do something for a UIViewController and ALL other UIViewcontroller added on top of UINavigationBar Stack?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is the approach I am using:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController hideTabBar];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tabBarController showTabBar];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

With this approach if I add something to the navigation stack the UITabBar will be shown again.

What about if I want UITabBar to be only shown when user navigate away to another tab or press back button, so not all cases of viewWillDisappear?

Pushing a UIViewController on top of navigation stack shouldn't change that

Comment: Can you please select and upvote any of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSNotification as well, so whenever you require to hide tab bar. At that moment fire that notification which will show/hide your tab bar.

Benifit of NSNotification is, you can fire that in entire application life cycle, and it does not be specific to any view controller or any class. One can use that independently from any class/view controller.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Regards,
Mrunal

Answer (score 3):

Do following in your view will appear method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

This will remove tabbar from the particular controller . and navigation stack will not change.

Comment: I know how to remove the tabBar(it's more involved than that actually). I want to know how to ensure that it's removed at the right time.

Comment: If I use viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear then it'll be called when I pop in some controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

At viewDidDisappear, I check if self.navigationController is empty. If it's empty I simply know that the view has been poped out of navigationController, which is the only way to get that view out of window hierarchy.